# Valve advice for chiller test rig

Tags: pressure, valves, flow-control, liquid

I am in the process of designing a chiller test rig, of which a very simplified diagram would be (the quick coupling might just be replaced by a non-return valve):

[image]

I am struggling to find the type of valve I need where the "??" is. The purpose of this valve is to create some load on the chiller and simulate having a real system connected to it. In other words, I (think I) want some resistance (flow restriction/increased pressure?) at that point in the circuit. Can you advise what kind of valve I would need for this (something manual ideally, not electrically actuated).

The fluid is a mix of ethylene glycol and water at 0°C. The chiller is set up to run at ~25psi at the outlet and the liquid flow rate is ~6 l/min.

Comment: A needle valve?

Comment: Many plumbing suppliers have pressure regulator valves, here is one. https://www.grainger.com/search?searchBar=true&searchQuery=water+pressure+regulator+valves